# R tidyquant removes colon for exchange code in key ratio tq_get

Tags: r, tidyquant

I'm trying to get some key ratios from Morningstart using tidyquant. Unfortunately all my stocks are on the ASX and tq_get appears to remove the colon indicating the exchange when I submit. The code and error I get are:

```
ratios <- tq_get('XASX:ALL', get = "key.ratios")
Warning message:
x = 'XASXALL', get = 'key.ratios': Error in UseMethod("as_list"): no applicable method for 'as_list' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

A search for "XASX:ALL" on the Morningstar website returns a successful search

Comment: I was not able to get it to work either. You may want to add a GitHub issue. https://github.com/business-science/tidyquant/issues

Comment: Thanks - Will do. Package is great btw.